# Assigning Columns from TXT to multiple TextBox in C# / Forms

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2013, data-conversion

NEW EDIT:

Hi,

I have worked on several codes and found the best solution to call a text file and assign each column to individual textboxes on "*Button1_Click*".

I also managed to write a code that allows me to edit the data in the textboxes and save the edited data with the original string format back to the TXT file on *"Button2_Click"*.

**Here is the problem now:**

When I re-call the edited TXT file and press on *Button1_Click*, things get messy: The format is gone and there are lots of breaks between the values.

There is no visible difference between the original TXT file and the Edited one, but the code just wont work with it.

I might have an Idea what the problem could be. When I call the original TXT file, each *row* is assigned to one element of a string array. >>> *When data has 5 rows, 5 elements are stored into one array*

But my SAVE code assigns the whole data to one single element of one array. Meaning that I have only *array[0]* available.

Since I am new to coding, I need your help on this.

Thanks!

Here is my Code:
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox3.Text = "";

```
        var table = new DataTable();

        var fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\root\Desktop\TXT.txt");



        var splitFileContents = (from f in fileContents select f.Split(' ')).ToArray();



        int maxLength = (from s in splitFileContents select s.Count()).Max();




        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add();
        }



        foreach (var line in splitFileContents)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row.ItemArray = (object[])line;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }



        for (int i = 0; i< maxLength; i++)
        {


            textBox1.Text += table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()+"\r\n";
            textBox2.Text += table.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString() + "\r\n";
            textBox3.Text += table.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString() + "\r\n";


        }

    }
```

**// SAVE Code**

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var table = new DataTable();
        string[] fileContents = new string[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text };
        var splitFileContents = (from f in fileContents select f.Split('\r')).ToArray();
        int maxLength = (from s in splitFileContents select s.Count()).Max();



        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add();
        }



        foreach (var line in splitFileContents)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row.ItemArray = (object[])line;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
      var test = "";



        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {


            test += table.Rows[0].ItemArray[i].ToString() +" " + table.Rows[1].ItemArray[i].ToString() + " " + table.Rows[2].ItemArray[i].ToString() + "\r\n" ;



        }

        textBox4.Text += test[1];

        var stringArr = new string[] { test };



        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\root\Desktop\TXT.txt", stringArr);
```

---

*ORIGINAL POST*

I'm new to C# and I want to import data from a text file to my GUI and split its values into multiple textboxes.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C63RB.png)

Meaning, that I want to assign column A to textBoxA and column B to textBoxB and so on..

I already found something on this, but can't get it running properly:

```
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

        string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TXT.txt");
        foreach (string record in records)
        {
            DataRow r = myDataTable.NewRow();
            string[] fields = record.Split('\t');
            /* Parse each field into the corresponding r column
             * ....
             */
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(r);
           /
        }
```

Once the data is assigned properly I want to edit the data in the textboxes and save those values into the original text file on buttonclick.

For this I already have a simple solution. Just added this code to the eventhandler and it works fine:

```
 File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\1msmoorGUI\msmoor\TEXT.TXT", textBoxA.Text +" "+ textBoxB.Text);
```

My main problem is the assignment of the columns to each of those textboxes using the above code.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.IO;

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Nr", typeof(int));
    //...your columns
    dt.Columns.Add("Notite", typeof(string));

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath))
                    {
                        string line;
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] Elements = line.Split('yourSplit');
                            DataRow row = myDataTable.NewRow();
                            row[0] = Elements[0];
                            //....
                            row[5] = Elements[5]; //depends on Elements
                            myDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
    foreach(DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
     { 
         textbox1.Text += row["col1"].ToString();  
          ///
         textbox2.Text += row["col2"].ToString();
     }

//save

 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path))
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
                {
                    string line = string.Format("\"{0}\"_\"{1}\"_\"{2}\"_\"{3}\"_\"{4}\"_\"{5}\"", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]);//or your format
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```